# Just installed Eclipse, won't run programs or show errors

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

new here, but I've got a simple question.

i have just installed the Eclipse Indigo IDE program on my laptop from my college website, as well as the Java Runtime Environment. While Eclipse itself is working and showing code, it won't run, every time I click on the run button, its says "The Selection can't be launched, and there are no recent launches". It also won't show any errors in the code either. This isn't a one time thing either, as I also downloaded it onto my home computer and it has the same problems. I get the impression I need to further configure it but I don't know what to do, can anyone help?

Comment: Searching YouTube for a good Eclipse/Java tutorial might be a better bet than asking here.

Comment: does the class that you are trying to run have main method?

Comment: Without providing us your code we really cant help you

Comment: The `Run` icon on eclipse menu will trigger the last run. It seems you have not ran any program yet. You need to right click in your code window (the class should have a main method) and click `run as -> java application`.

Comment: I haven't actually done anything with it yet. I just downloaded it an hour ago on the laptop.

Comment: Okay, ran a test program with the code:                                         package test:                                                                                                                                                            public static void main(string[] args  {                                        System.out.println("Testing");                                           Seems to be working now on the laptop.

Comment: this can happen if you import a project wrong and all the files show up as uneditable java files (like external libraries do)